# how to figure out dependencies in javascript project

Tags: javascript, dependencies

Is there a quick and neat way to figure out dependency graph within a javascript project.

Specifically, I want to find out if a given javascript file is of any relevance or can be dropped off.

I have a project where numerous Javascript files are included in a project and I doubt if all of them are required.

Answer (score 0):

You can check all files that are being used under the **Network** tab of Browser Developer tools.

Also you can use chrome auditing tool to see unused CSS & can optimize the order styles & scripts. [Dev Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find unused files you can just grep the project and search for references, something like:

```
grep -r --include='*.js' --exclude-dir={node_modules} "my-file.js" .
```

could help.